# Why I'm getting exception Instantiating material due to calling renderer.material during edit mode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In `EditorWindow` script type:

Inside this method:

```c#
public static void CopyData()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedComponents.Length; i++)
    {
        if (selectedComponents[i])
        {
            if (copyTypeCount.ContainsKey(t[i]))
                copyTypeCount[t[i]] = copyTypeCount[t[i]] + 1;
            else
                copyTypeCount.Add(t[i], 1);

            for (int j = 0; j < selectedFields[i].Length; j++)
            {
                if (selectedFields[i][j])
                    fieldVals[i][j] = fields[i][j].GetValue(components[i]);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < selectedProperties[i].Length; j++)
            {
                if (selectedProperties[i][j])
                {
                    if (properties[i][j].CanRead && properties[i][j].GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
                        propertyVals[i][j] = properties[i][j].GetValue(components[i], null); //<<<<< Problem here at this line
                    else
                        Debug.LogWarning(properties[i][j].Name + " could not be copied.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the line:

```c#
propertyVals[i][j] = properties[i][j].GetValue(components[i], null);
```

The variable types for completeness:

```c#
bool[] selectedComponents 

Dictionary<Type, int> copyTypeCount

Type[] t

bool[][] selectedFields 

bool[][] fieldVals

List<FieldInfo>[] fields

bool[][] selectedProperties

List<PropertyInfo>[] properties 

object[][] propertyVal 

Component[] components
```

The exception message:

> Instantiating material due to calling renderer.material during edit mode. This will leak materials into the scene. You most likely want to use renderer.sharedMaterial instead

The complete exception message:

> Instantiating material due to calling renderer.material during edit mode. This will leak materials into the scene. You most likely want to use renderer.sharedMaterial instead.
>   System.Reflection.MonoProperty:GetValue(Object, Object[])
>   ComponentCopier:CopyData() (at Assets/ComponentTester/Editor/ComponentTester.cs:265)
>   ComponentCopier:OnGUI() (at Assets/ComponentTester/Editor/ComponentTester.cs:195)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

But no where in my script I'm doing any Instantiating or any renderer.material
So I'm not sure why this exception is happened.

The exception again is on the line:

```c#
propertyVals[i][j] = properties[i][j].GetValue(components[i], null);
```

And line 195 is inside `OnGUI`:

```c#
if (GUILayout.Button("Copy", GUILayout.Height(30)))
{
    CopyData();

    if (closeAfterCopy == true)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Before the code was to `this.Close();` all the time to avoid this exception.
But I don't want to close the window all the time so I added a check with a flag. But if it's not closed then I'm getting this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a warning message, not exception at all.

When you do `var mat = renderer.material`, a new material is instantiated and replace the renderer's material property, the purpose for this mechanism is to prevent changing other renderers' materials by chance.

Since the instantiated material is not an asset, so when you get material property in editor script, the material won't be properly saved.

If you want your editor script run normally, avoid to get property like `Renderer.material`, `Renderer.materials`, `MeshFilter.mesh`...

Comment: I understand that already but I don't understand where in my script it's doing it ? Where in this line propertyVals[i][j] = properties[i][j].GetValue(components[i], null); I'm doing any  instantiate ? And as the exception say I should use sharedMaterial instead but not sure where and how in my script. I want to work with it also in editor mode but I can't figure out where and how to handle it.

Comment: It seems to me like exception since in the editor there is a red sign not the yellow one. https://imgur.com/a/6YZhPiG

Comment: Don't you know what is `PropertyInfo.GetValue`? When you access `Renderer.material` the material  instantiated.

Comment: Not really never read the documents about it. Tried to google for it now but no documents.

Comment: And as last part I've said, avoid get these properties, check the names like `if(properties[i][j].Name == "material")` ... skip copy.

Comment: Take a look at [reflection in c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) may help.

Comment: Ok I'm using the checking of the names also for ""mesh since I'm gettingh two exceptions  the second one is on Meshfilter.mesh. But then if it's not copying this properties won't the copy will be completed ? I mean the idea is to copy from an gameobject all the properties and components and the values settings. And then In my script I have a part where I paste it to another gameobject. But if not copied the materils and meshes it will not be a completed copy.

Comment: Why not use [EditorUtility.CopySerialized](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.CopySerialized.html)?

Comment: I will try to use the  EditorUtility.CopySerialized I should change some of my script. But it seems a good idea.